# Как получить редактируемую строку в RichTextBox WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь прикрутить проверку ошибок в RichTextBox. Не знаю, как получить конкретный Block из FlowDocument, в который вводятся, удаляются или вставляются данные. Желательно получить индекс блока, т.к. понадобится узнать, что было записано в предыдущих. Проверка не похожа на проверку орфографии и класс Validation не подходит. Кто может подсказать, что и как использовать?

Comment: Вроде бы подходит [`TextChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), но он даёт пустой список изменений, когда вы, например, меняете всего одно свойство (например, Bold-участок превращаете в Bold-Italic).

Comment: Интересуют только операции ввода, удаления и вставки. Да, TextChanged подходит,для них, но как узнать Block, в котором произошли изменения? Могу считать CaretPosition, но как с помощью него строку, в которой сработало событие-не понятно.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Можно подписаться на [`TextChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) и смотреть на список `Changes`, в нём есть `Offset`, из которого легко получить `Paragraph`, то есть, блок (а значит, и его номер).

```
var offs = change.Offset;
var ptr = doc.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(offs);
var paragraph = ptr.Paragraph;
var parIndex = ((System.Collections.IList)doc.Blocks).IndexOf(paragraph);
```

Полный компилируемый пример:

```
<Window x:Class="FlowDocumentWatch.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Flow document watch" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RichTextBox TextChanged="OnChange">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>Paragraph 1</Paragraph>
                <Paragraph>Paragraph 2</Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
        <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ChangeTexts}" Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> ChangeTexts { get; } =
        new ObservableCollection<string>();

    int changeNo = 0;
    void OnChange(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var doc = ((RichTextBox)sender).Document;
        foreach (var change in e.Changes)
        {
            var offs = change.Offset;
            var ptr = doc.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(offs);
            var paragraph = ptr.Paragraph;
            var parIndex = ((System.Collections.IList)doc.Blocks).IndexOf(paragraph);
            ChangeTexts.Add(
                $"{changeNo}: added {change.AddedLength}, removed {change.RemovedLength}" +
                $" at position {change.Offset}, paragraph #{parIndex}");
        }
        changeNo++;
    }
}
```

---

Заметьте, что `TextChanged` доставляется, но содержит пустой список `Changes` в случае, когда в результате редактирования меняется только атрибут и более ничего. Например, если вы выделите кусок текста, сделаете его сначала жирным, а потом наклонным (<kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + I</kbd>), то нотификация придёт только при первом изменении, но не при втором. Я не знаю, как с этим бороться.